# If iterated limits exist and are equal does that mean one of the limits is uniform?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Suppose I have a double indexed sequence $a_{mn}$ and I know that the iterated limits satisfy
$$\lim_n \lim_m a_{nm} = \lim_m\lim_n a_{nm} = a.$$
Does this imply anything about the uniform convergence of $\lim_n a_{mn}$?

Comment: How do you define uniform convergence of **a limit**?

Comment: Sorry I mean that do we get that for example $a_{mn} \to a_{m\infty}$ uniformly in $m$, as $n \to \infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want to achieve, but this should be a counterexample:
$$a_{nm} = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if } m \ne n, \\ 42 & \text{if } n = m. \end{cases}$$
Then, both iterated limits exist and are equal, and the limit $\lim_{n,m \to \infty} a_{n,m}$ does not exist.